# How to generate model classes for existing oracle database in asp core 2.2?

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to make database first approach in asp core 2.2.

My problem is that I can't find anything helpful to generate my model classes from my existing oracle database, I want to do it by anyway I don't care, but all my attempts failed so any help would be much appreciated

**Edit 1**:
I see that EF Core is always mentioned in the answer but it has no provider, I'm not sticking to it I'm really asking for any approach to do what I want so if there is a way with Dapper, NHibernate or anything else I will be happy to use it as it get the job done.

**Edit 2**:
I tried Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore, it generates classes based on database tables like a charm but it's paid unfortunately. later I used Dapper and had to create classes on my own.

Comment: Please [provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) showing what you're attempting to do and where you're stuck. Otherwise, it's pretty much guesswork as far as what sort of array/switch will actually help you here.

Comment: @Simonare Why I would put anything when it's unrelated to the question and will not add any clarification to the point ?. 
I'm really asking a simple as someone asking the same thing for sql server but in my case there is no tutorials or docs to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is coming in later, this was finally solved by oracle itself as they released their provider for EF core [Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/2.19.60).

Then follow the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) but use `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore` and the **proper connection string**

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools in the market

- [Devart's Entity Developer](https://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper)
- [Scaffold-DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db) or [dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)
- [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools)

**Edit**

Right now, Oracle does not have support for Entity Framework Core. Which means you need to use third party library in order to use Entity Framework Core with Oracle.

Devart has [dotConnect for Oracle](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) Database Driver (adapter) which supports EF Core.

Please see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/#future-providers) for Future Plans about Oracle Database Providers

**Edit: OP Stated that Only Mapping/Scaffolding will be enough**

You may consider to use Entity Framework to scaffold your model and migrate it to EF Core Manually.You may need little tweaks since two framework has some differences.

Comment: Where is the oracle part for that? none of this work with oracle I have already tried all of these and more that's why I'm asking

Comment: check my answer please. I didn't understand your problem clearly. Now It makes sense. thank you for clarification

Comment: np, OK let's take ef core aside, I only want to generate model classes based on my existing oracle database something to do the mapping at least, after that I will use anything dapper, nhibernate, ... etc. I used LLBLgen pro with PostgreSQL and it was fantastic but with oracle in asp core it dosn't work

Comment: you may consider to scaffold your model in Entity Framework with Oracle and copy your classes to EF Core. You may need little tweaks since two framework has some differences. unfortunately you need Oracle Driver which has support for EF Core Scaffolding. AFAIK only Devart has it

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [Oracle is currently conducting a private beta of their EF Core provider.](https://community.oracle.com/message/15003587#15003587) You could either try to join the beta or keep waiting for the release of the public beta, which is announced for Dec., 2018 (seems to be delayed).

A documentation about [reverse-engineering yor db can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db#install-entity-framework-core).

Comment: I saw it too but I can't just believe that there is nothing to do this, also I'm asking for anything thing really anything not just ef core

Answer (score 0):

Try using this provider https://github.com/CrazyJson/Citms.EntityFrameworkCore.Oracle
You can download it from NuGet-solution - Citms.EntityFrameworkCore.Oracle

Make sure you've installed its dependencies:
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core (>= 2.18.3)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 2.2.0)

Comment: I tried to use it with Scaffolding to generate classes but it failed